# AngularJS navigation

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement that states:
Logged in user can view employee list, individual employee view etc. For administrator, left navigation menu provides list of different entities and administrator should be able to view list of all employees for selected entity.

But I need to navigate administrator to home page once the entity is changed in left navigation drop down. employee-config.js uses employeeListCtrl and home page has its own controller (defined in separate home-config.js)

How to navigate from

```
$stateProvider.state("employeeList",{
                        url: "/employee/list",
                        templateUrl: cfg.URL_ROOT + "/IC/employee-app/employee-list/employee-list.html",
                        data: {
                            listStateName: "homeMain"   // This is not working
                        },
                        controller: "employeeListCtrl as vm"
                    });
```

TO

```
$stateProvider
            .state("homeMain", {
                url: "/home/main",
                templateUrl: cfg.URL_ROOT + "/IC/home-app/home-main/home-main.html",
                data: {
                    listStateName: "homeMain"
                },
                controller: "homeMainController as vm"
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about just  redirecting to other states you can do with simple

> $location.url("here your state names like 'employeeList')

and if you are talking about authorization of the current users this you can do with $stateprovider's  onstatechangestart function in .config  i would share this code for reference.

> Blockquote
>
> $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
>   $rootScope.onLoading();   var authorised = null;
>           if (next.access !== undefined && next.access.requiresLogin) {
>              var userLoggedIn =   UserService.getCurrentUser();
>               authorization.getConditions(next.access,userLoggedIn);
>           } });

there you  can find  next.access  with reference to routes

> ```
> ROUTER.when('dashboard_path', '/dashboard', {
>   controller : 'DashboardCtrl',
>   templateUrl : CONFIG.prepareViewTemplateUrl('videos/index'),
>    access: {
>         requiresLogin: true,
>         requiredPermissions: ['admin', 'AccountManager'],
>         permissionType: 'AtLeastOne'
>     }
> });
> ```

there access would store values and we can get it into  routechange function and compare.

Please note there is  authorization is service which check server side user session existance.

please let me know if it helps or needed more details.